# You know me, but you don't know me. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

Though I am not always bright

You use me day and night

Once I was black and blue

But I'm not silver and grey

One of me gives you more than this

But not all who know me, know me

I don't discriminate

Old and young, rich and poor

I am selfish yet not

I won't die if I'm selfish

Hint #1

> I was born in 1976

Comment: Do you mean "But I'm *now*..."?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier no. the word "not" is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> A meme

Because you were

> Born in 1976, in Richard's Dawkin's book "The Selfish Gene"

Though I am not always bright 
You use me day and night

> A meme is an idea (but not always a 'bright' idea). We are constantly having ideas, whether we want to or not!

Once I was black and blue 
But I'm not silver and grey

> This refers to the viral picture of 'The Dress' that some people saw as blue & black, or gold and white.

One of me gives you more than this 
But not all who know me, know me

> The word 'meme' has also been used to describe a picture plus a funny caption (ie. 'more than' just an idea). The correct name for this kind of 'meme' is 'image macro'.

I don't discriminate 
Old and young, rich and poor

> Ideas are spread to everyone

I am selfish yet not 
I won't die if I'm selfish

> The concept was coined in 'The Selfish Gene', but memes are not really living things, so can't truly be called selfish.

Answer (score 2):

and The answer is:

> iMac (by Apple)

**section 1:**

> Though I am not always bright 
>   You use me day and night

means:

> The iMac was a great success in relation to the lack of popularity the Macintosh had until that time among the general public and until then Apple was not bright at all but today people use their iMac day and night.

**section 2:**

> Once I was black and blue 
>   But I'm not silver and grey

means:

> This computer broke two conventions in the world of personal computing When it was launched: it included a combination of colors of blue and white and its envelope was transparent. The iMac was a breakthrough in design and a change in the usual beige and gray colors on personal computers.

**section 3:**

> One of me gives you more than this 
>   But not all who know me, know me

means:

> **One of me gives you more than this**-Today the computer gives many options of colors and models in colors such as snow, Dalmatian stains, chrysanthemum, graphite, and other marketers for all.**But not all who know me, know me**-People today don't know what its benefits were because of them was the big breakthrough of iMac.

**section 4:**

> I don't discriminate 
>   Old and young, rich and poor

means:

> **Old and young**-The iOS operating system installed on iMac is by far the best because it is simple and easy to operate and so people of all ages and ages can use it, **rich and poor** -For the Macintosh market, which has always been beyond the reach of most consumers, the iMac has innovated at a cheap price (less than $ 1,300 - a breakthrough in terms of prices for Macintosh models), pointing out that Apple intends to turn to the consumer market first and thus give everyone the opportunity to experience its devices.

**section 5:**

> I am selfish yet not 
>   I won't die if I'm selfish

means:

> iMac= **i** mac=very selfish,But the truth is that his name implies that it connects to the **i**nternet in a fast way, which was new at the time of its first release and a great advantage without which this computer "died" .

**Hint #1:**
means:

> On April 1, 1976, Apple was founded by Steve Jobs and Steve Wozniak